# Retrieving latitude and longitude from mysql, passing it to google maps api

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I am a complete beginner and just wanting to know if there is a simple was of passing these locations to google maps which is in a script in my HTML.

I can retrieve the coordinates fine like this

PHP (this works):

```
<?php
require_once "sql.php";

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

    $result = array();
    $result['success'] = false;

    $order_by = $_REQUEST['sort_by'];

    $query = "SELECT venue_name, latitude, longitude, id  FROM venues";
        if ($result_set = Sql::query($query)) {
            $result['success'] = true;
            $result['message'] = "All Venues" ;
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result_set);
            $result['rows'] = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i<$rows; $i++) {
                $tmpRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
                $result['rows'][$i] = $tmpRow;
            }
        } else {
             $result['message'] = "Failed to read Cafes" ;
        }

        print(json_encode($result));
```

JQuery (part of a separate .js, this works):

```
function success_get_locations(response) {
if(response.success) {
    var cafe_loc = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
        var venue_name = response.rows[i].venue_name;
        var venue_lat = response.rows[i].latitude;
        var venue_long = response.rows[i].longitude;
        var id = response.rows[i].id;

        cafe_loc += venue_name + venue_lat + venue_long + id; 
    }
}
```

}

I just need to know how to add these locations from `function success_locations()` in my JQuery to google maps `var locations []` which is in my HTML here:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
</script>
```

thanks
James

Comment: From the [articles section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/) [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)

Comment: I have read some of the articles. But I am a real beginner so was struggling with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit doesn't make much sense:

```
    cafe_loc += venue_name + venue_lat + venue_long + id;
```

You're taking the nice array of results, sucking out the bits into individual variables, then concatentating them all into one big string. e.g. For your sample locations in the JS code, you'd actually be building

```
Bondi Beach-33.890542151.2748564
```

Why not just leave them as the array they are already? Or if the ordering of the array isn't correct, you could build a NEW array with the elements in the proper order:

```
locs_for_google = [];
for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
   locs_for_google[i] = [
       response.rows[i].venue_name,
       response.rows[i].latitude,
       response.rows[i].longitude,
       response.rows[i].id
   ];
}
```

Comment: ah yeah I would happily leave it as it is! So how do I pass `locs_for_google` to the map script in the html? Do I need to first pass it to a global variable in the .js file? cheers

Comment: if you don't need to dynamically update the list via ajax, then simply dump your PHP array out into the js block, e.g. `var locs_for_google = <?php echo json_encode($locs_from_db); ?>;`.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Ideally it would update dynamically with ajax, what would be the simplest way of doing that?

Comment: about the same. dump your initial list into the js block literally at page generation time. then use an ajax call to fetch an updated list afterwards. then it'd be as simple as `$.get(......, function(data) { locs_for_google = data; });`.

Comment: Ah right I understand. I know a bit more than I did yesterday so thank you very much.