# How do i pull sql data and pass to google maps API

Tags: javascript, c#, json, sql-server, google-maps-markers

please be kind, I'm new to coding. Can I ask that you explain things as simply as you can for me. I have an sql table that contains building information inc. Longitude and latitude(over 5 thousand buildings). I need to pull this data into visual studio and then pass it to my Google maps api to drop markers according to the lat and long. There are tutorials using php but we don't use php. I really need and appreciate any help you can give me. I have created a json file from sql and copied it into a json file in VS. So the bones are there, I just need help putting it together.

Thank you
Mike.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio to build your application? There are plenty of tutorials on connecting from an application to an SQL server. How are you planning to connect to your front end/API?

Comment: Yes using visual studio. I have json file which contains all the building details, I have the Google maps api setup. I now jeed to pull the data from the json file into the api to drop the markers. Ill post a view of my json and the application so far as it may help you to help me.

Comment: You can check out this documentation on how you can load your json data and display it on your map. [Importing Data into Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data)

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure. which takes `buildingId` as an input parameter. and select the latitude and longitude in SP. you can pass these values to the API

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this thread. Maybe it would help you with jQuery and Javascript.
[Retrieving latitude and longitude from mysql, passing it to google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374359/retrieving-latitude-and-longitude-from-mysql-passing-it-to-google-maps-api)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't use php as its not supported on our servers. It has been suggested I use a hidden aspx file and pass the data from there using json and java script.